# Before trigger in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a trigger where if the no tickets are less than the no of adults then value 1 will be inserted in trig table.But, I am getting an error.The code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ch 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON packagebooking
IF(tick.tickets<packagebooking.Adult
     AND tick.Package_id=packagebooking.Package_id)
Begin atomic
insert into trig values(1)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(tick.tickets<packagebooking.Adult
     AND tick.Package_id=packagebooking.Pa' at line 4.
```

What changes should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for trigger creation has an error, place the IF statement inside the FOR EACH ROW as shown below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ch BEFORE INSERT
   ON `database`.`table`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF(tick.tickets<packagebooking.Adult
          AND tick.Package_id=packagebooking.Package_id)
      THEN Begin atomic
           insert into trig values(1)
      END IF;
   END;
```

Comment: I tried to execute this trigger but now i m getting an error in line no. 7 i.e. where insert query is written.

Comment: I just copied your code. See this link for the proper syntax for an insert statement. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp